# Show and Hide with CSS Animation in Component

Tags: css, angular, angular6, css-animations, angular7

I created an Angular side bar I am trying to show and hide it with a CSS animation [Online Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mt5ikd):

The sidebar component relies on a Service to know when to hide and show:

```
<div id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{'hide': sidebarService.hidden, 'show': !sidebarService.hidden}">

  <button type="button" (click)="sidebarService.toggle()">
    Close Sidebar
  </button>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

The CSS I am using is the following:

```
@keyframes show {
  from {left: -100%;}
  to {left: 0;}
}

@keyframes hide {
  from {left: 0;}
  to {left: -100%;}
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;   
  left: -100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;     
  width: 100%;
}

.hide {
  animation-name: hide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.show {
  animation-name: show;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

I found 2 problems:

1 - The sidebar appears initially visible and it closes just after;

2 - When click to open the sidebar opens but when finished it disappears.

I am not sure what I am missing here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the you set a keyframes animation hide in which you set the `from : 0%` and `to: -100%` . That means that the animation starts with the sidebar at 0.

So it goes from -100% ( which you set default on #sidebar ) , goes to the `from` position of `0%` and then goes to the `to` position. That's why the sidebar appears on load.

Then the show animation hides the sidebar again because you don't set a `animation-fill-mode`which should be `forwards`. If not, at the end of any animation, the element returns to it's default position which you set to `-100%` on `#sidebar`. So it hides again.

( in this case ) You can skip the animation altogether and just use transitions

```html
#sidebar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;   
  left: -100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;     
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}

#sidebar.hide {
  left: -100%;
}

#sidebar.show {
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css as below:

set `left: -100%;` in `.hide` instead of use in `#sidebar`

**Why?**

if you set `left: -100%;` in `#sidebar` after the `show` aniamtion finish the `left` back to declaretion as in `#sidebar` and not stay as you set in `@keyframes`

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdieph?file=src/app/sidebar.component.css)

```
#sidebar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;   
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;     
  width: 100%;
}

.hide {
  animation-name: hide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  left: -100%;
}

.show {
  animation-name: show;
  animation-duration: 1s;

}
```

Comment: I tried that but if you check your example the sidebar appears initially open ... And should be closed.

Comment: When I run my example the sidebar is close until click on button

Comment: Sorry but it is open at start ... Anyone care to confirm?

Comment: please see in F12 what class apply to DOM first `show/hide` maybe you need to "play" with `ngClass`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is where you're defining the `left: -100%` in your css file.

My suggestion is to do like that, placing `left: -100%` inside the `.hide` class and not direct in the container.

```
#sidebar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;   
  /*left: -100%;*/
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;     
  width: 100%;

}

.hide {
  animation-name: hide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  left:-100%;
}

.show {
  animation-name: show;
  animation-duration: 1s;

}
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried your suggestion but with that the sidebar appears initially opened when it should be closed ...

Comment: Ah you mean the initial flicker. You could set 'display:none' in the '.hide' and 'display:block' in the '.show' section. That will do the trick.

Comment: That solves the initial flicker but when you hide it is just disappears with no animation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-55rey9

Comment: I see two options: 1 - Do like the suggestion of 'Milhai T' below using Transitions and forget about animations. 2 - Define a start class for your sidebar in your angular class other than 'hide'. As it is today, it starts already with hide class attached which triggers the keyFrame 'hide', leading to the flicker effect during initial load.